# Having incorrect solutions when program executes,

Tags: c#

I've been working on a two class BMI Calculator for my class. I finally have managed to debug on get the program to execute. However I noticed that it wont let me enter height or weight as a decimal.

Example

putting 6.4 for height causes it to crash

Putting 6 height and 220 weight always seems to declare underweight and show incorrect bmi reading

example:

Height 6

Weight 220

BMI: score $0.09

It's calculating the BMI wrong. Looking at the code I can't seem to identify why its calculating this wrong.

-Edit- Managed to get it to take decimals! (Thank you everyone!) However it still seems to be messing up calculating the BMI

-Edit- Code Works!

(Code Part 1) *Updated Mk2*

```
using System;

namespace Calculator
{

public class BMICalc
{
    private const
        decimal REQ = 703;
    private decimal weightPerson;
    private decimal heightPerson;

    public BMICalc()
    {

    }
    public BMICalc(decimal weiP, decimal heiP)
    {
        this.weightPerson = weiP;
        this.heightPerson = heiP;

    }

    public decimal SetBmi()
    {
        decimal bmi;
        bmi = Convert.ToDecimal((this.weightPerson * 0.45m) / ((this.heightPerson * 12 * 0.025m) * (this.heightPerson * 12 * 0.025m)));

        if (bmi < 18.5m)

        {
            Console.WriteLine("UnderWeight");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        if (bmi > 18.5m && bmi < 25.0m)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Normal");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        if (bmi > 25.0m && bmi < 29.9m)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OverWeight");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        if (bmi > 29.9m && bmi < 40.0m)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Obese");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        return bmi;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "\tCalculator" +
            "\n\n Weight:" + this.weightPerson +
            "\n\n Height:" + this.heightPerson +
            "\n\n BMI Score:" + SetBmi().ToString();


    }
}
}
```

Code (Part 2) *Updated Mk 2*

```
   namespace Calculator
{
public class App
{
    public static void Main() // 
    {
        decimal heiP, weiP;

        heiP = InputHeight();

        weiP = InputWeight();



        BMICalc bmiCal = new BMICalc(weiP, heiP);

        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine(bmiCal.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    public static decimal InputHeight()
    {
        decimal hNumber;

        Console.Write("Please enter your height: ");
        hNumber = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
        return hNumber;
    }

    public static decimal InputWeight()
    {
        Decimal wNumber;

        Console.Write("Please enter your weight: ");

        wNumber = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
        return wNumber;
    }


}
}
```

Comment: "However I noticed that it wont let me enter height or weight as a decimal" - That's because you're explicitly expecting an integer - `Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())`. You're also storing the values as integers, which means when calculating the BMI, you are performing [Integer Division](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegerDivision.html). I would imagine fixing your application to deal with and store doubles/decimals would fix your calculation issue as well

Comment: Can you post any exceptions that the program is throwing when it "crashes"?

Comment: All of your inputs and calculations assume the numbers are doubles/decimals, but all your datatypes are ints. This will cause truncation errors at best and cause crashes at worst. (Which, incidentally, is what you are getting.)

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: Alright. I managed to change it so it can now take decimals! But it's still calculating the BMI wrong unfortunatly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're input parameters into the constructor expects weight (weiP), height (heiP) (in that order) while you're passing height, weight from  BMICalc bmiCal = new BMICalc(heiP, weiP);

That's the reason the value being output is incorrect. Interchange the parameters and it should be fine.

EDIT

Since you're entering the weight in Lbs and height in feet, you would need to convert feet into inches ( multiplying by 12) and then also multiplying the height and weight by the conversion metric.

So the formula would be:

```
bmi = Convert.ToDecimal((this.weightPerson * 0.45) / ((this.heightPerson * 12 * 0.025) * (this.heightPerson * 12 * 0.025)));
```

The currency comes in when it uses the ToString() overridden method. The format specified there is for currency.

Comment: Alright I swapped out and it's now BMICalc(weiP, heiP) And now it is doing math. However it's still calculating BMI wrong also its doing it as a currency for some odd reason? example 6.5 and 220 generate 3,660.59

Comment: Fixed the currency didn't even realize that to be honest. (I based this code off an example in the textbook that was a program for a car ticket) Anyways what your saying does make sense! I tried putting the code you provided me before it does the BMI Calculation however it's giving me errors saying "Operator '*' cannot be applied to decimal or double

Comment: I think you might need to cast the 0.45 and 0.025 as decimal and that should take care of the error you've mentioned.

Comment: Alright it fixed the error. (Thank you) However it's still giving the same result as I mentioned before. I was supposed to put this line between decimal bmi; and bmi = (this.weightPerson * BMICalc.REQ) / (this.heightPerson * this.heightPerson); right? Maybe it's the equation that is wrong or maybe all the if statements.

Comment: bmi = (this.weightPerson * BMICalc.REQ) / (this.heightPerson * this.heightPerson);

This equation is incorrect. This equation needs to be replaced with the code I mentioned earlier.

Comment: Whooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooaaaaaaaaaa!. It did fix it! I was really confused because the BMI formula had weight x 703 and this completely overrides it. Thank you for your help and putting up with a newbie such as myself. I wish you the best of nights and a wonderful time ^ _ ^